# how to save and get data to local storage in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

first I post to get a token, then I save the response in local storage, how do I save and retrieve the token data in local storage using react native?

this is my splashscreen.js

```
import { api } from '../../helpers'

const getAppToken = () => {
    const post = {
      user: 'dummy',
      secret: 'dummy'
    }

    api.post('/v1/mp/authenticate', post)
      .then(res => {
        const { Data, Message } = res.data
        if (Message === 'SUCCESS') {
          setToken('app-token', Data.token)
          navigation.replace('MainApp')
        }
      })
  }

  const setToken = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error')
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAppToken()
  }, [])
```

and this is api.js from helpers directory

```
import { axios, AsyncStorage } from '../../libraries'

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'dummy',
  headers: {
    'X-APP-TOKEN': 'dummy',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'content-type': 'application/merge -patch+json'
  }
})

AsyncStorage.getItem('app-token')
  .then(token => {
    api.interceptors.request.use(config => {
      config.headers = { Authorization: `Bearer${token}` }
      return config
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
})
```

when the AsyncStorage.getItem ('app-token') located in the api.js file is run it gets a 401 response

Comment: Store data with Json stringfy, then get with Json parse.

Comment: Write data to console or alert check if token accepted from api and what accepted. Then write to local

Comment: the results are out, but I can't get to AsyncStorage which is in the api.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**initialPage screen**

```
 axios.post('https://your_apikey', {}, {
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic c2hvcHBpbmdfb2F1dGhfY2xpZW50OnNob3BwaW5nX29hdXRoX3NlY3JldA==` }
    }).then(async (response) => {
        console.log(response.data.data.access_token);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.data.access_token);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

**Homepage**//my project as ur wish were u want(second initial page )

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
        async config => {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")
            if (token) {
                // console.log('if condition', await AsyncStorage.getItem("token"));
                config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token//pass ur token entire app once ur set
            } else {
                console.log('config');
            }
            return config
        },
        error => {
            return Promise.reject(error)
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

Get user data then set token to local storage

```
await login(req)
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({customerToken: res.token, customerLoading: false});
          if (res.token) {
            this.setState({customerLoading: true});
            AsyncStorage.setItem('customerToken', JSON.stringify(res.token));
            let tokenData = {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${res.token}`,
            };
```

get token from local

```
await AsyncStorage.getItem('customerToken')
      .then(ct => {
        if (ct !== null) {
          // We have data!!
          const c_token = JSON.parse(ct);
          let tokenData = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${c_token}`,
          };
```